# How do I select a new SMTP "Primary Server"?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, settings, smtp

On my iPhone (iOS 11.2.5), I had to change the SMTP server for my e-mail account.  I was able to add the new SMTP server, which appeared under "OTHER SMTP SERVERS".  I was also able to turn off the old SMTP server (which is shown under "PRIMARY SERVER", so I only have the new SMTP server active.  I am able to send mail successfully.

My question is: How do I switch my Primary Server to be the one that is active?  Does it even matter?

[image: screenshot of SMTP settings]

Comment: As the note as the bottom states, "If Mail is unsuccessful using the primary server, it will try the other SMTP servers in succession." This means it doesn't really matter because if you've disabled the primary server it will move on down the list until it can send through one.

Comment: Except it doesn't actually do that. Right now I cannot send any mail because my primary is defunct & any 'secondary' is completely ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't figured out a way to rearrange the servers so that a different one is the Primary, but I was able to work around it by simply tapping on the Primary server entry and change the details so that it points to the server that I want.  That way, the one I am actually using is the Primary.

As Christian said in the comments, it doesn't matter, because if I only have one server actually turned on, that is the one that Mail will use.

Comment: Mine wouldn't use any other server if it couldn't reach the primary, just complained at me:\ I eventually got mine to work this way. It was using a defunct server that no longer existed on the phone as an account at all. I'd hoped I could get them to sync from the Mac if I changed it there, but no. After some initial trouble getting it to Verify, this method worked.