# How do I eliminate SMTP servers in the settings that I no longer use?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, settings, smtp

Earlier today, I asked a [question about SMTP server settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338656/62960) on my iPhone (iOS 11.2.5).  I've more or less figured that one out.  I realize that it doesn't really matter, but how do I get rid of all these extra SMTP entries that I no longer need?

[image: screenshot of unused SMTP servers]

Answer (score 1):

From the same screen as your screenshot, click each of those smtp servers.  On the next screen at the bottom in red “delete server”.

Comment: Can you please edit to show how to get to that screen in the first place and maybe include a screenshot?

Comment: When I tap on each of those SMTP servers, there is no “delete server” button.

Comment: You need to empty username and password fields of the SMTP server you want to delete, save, then the delete button is visible